# Directory User Phone Numbers not displaying

Tags: google-app-maker

User HomePhones, WorkPhones, etc. from a directory are not showing up when I am using AppMaker Directory.

AppMaker states that these fields will be included if our organization uses them:

> "If your organization’s Google Cloud Directory includes these fields, your apps can retrieve them."

Is this a bug or is there an error with my Directory?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if phones are filled for users in your domain. Domain Admin can check it in [Google Admin - Users](https://admin.google.com/AdminHome#UserList:).

Comment: Yes, fields are filled in for users in the following categories: Home, Work, Mobile. Additionally, the PrimaryAddress field is not displaying the full address, just the Zip Code

Comment: Could you report the problem from App Maker: Menu -> Report the problem?

It would be very helpful if you can provide Admin Directory record for one of the users with phone(s) set. Please remove any confidential data from the output. You can retrieve it with script like:

function getUser() {
  var userEmail = 'liz@example.com';
  var user = AdminDirectory.Users.get(userEmail);
  Logger.log('User data:\n %s', JSON.stringify(user, null, 2));
}

( code from: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory )

Comment: Thanks Vasyl. I was able to retrieve the phone numbers using AdminDirectory advanced service as you suggest and reported the problem to Issue Tracker. Hope they are able to figure out what is not working with the Directory model.